# Client-Go, How to watch for newly created Pods in Kubernetes

Tags: go, kubernetes, client-go

I need to write a `golang` application with the help of [client-go](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go) which will listen/watch a particular namespace for any of these events:

- A new pod has been created
- A pod has been deleted
- A new container has been added to existing pods
- Image for container for any pod has changed

And I want to communicate this information to another application application running in other namespace.

I am really new to the `client-go` library and I searched their documentation but couldn't find something similar to [Events in Kopf](https://kopf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events/)

**I am new to this library and I couldn't find a method/function of doing this. I don't need to have the full code of doing this, but I appreciate where I can look into, so I can find my way out**

Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 3):

You can create a clientset from parsing the kubeconfig file and then use this clientset to create a sharedInformerfactory for your particular namespace. Get a informer for your pods and add Event Handler functions. Implement those functions according to your requirement. You can check for container updates between oldPod and newPod in the `OnUpdate` function. Use the clientset for however you want to communicate with other applications. I would say explore the methods that clientset implements to get a detailed idea how it works.

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    corev1 "k8s.io/api/core/v1"
    "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/runtime"
    "k8s.io/client-go/informers"
    "k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes"
    "k8s.io/client-go/tools/cache"
    "k8s.io/client-go/tools/clientcmd"
    "k8s.io/client-go/util/homedir"
    "k8s.io/klog/v2"
    "path/filepath"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    // parse the .kubeconfig file
    var kubeconfig *string
    if home := homedir.HomeDir(); home != "" {
        kubeconfig = flag.String("kubeconfig", filepath.Join(home, ".kube", "config"), "(optional) absolute path to the kubeconfig file")
    } else {
        kubeconfig = flag.String("kubeconfig", "", "absolute path to the kubeconfig file")
    }
    flag.Parse()

    // create config from the kubeconfig
    config, err := clientcmd.BuildConfigFromFlags("", *kubeconfig)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // create the clientset
    clientSet, err := kubernetes.NewForConfig(config)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // stop signal for the informer
    stopper := make(chan struct{})
    defer close(stopper)
    
    // create shared informers for resources in all known API group versions with a reSync period and namespace
    factory := informers.NewSharedInformerFactoryWithOptions(clientSet, 10*time.Second, informers.WithNamespace("demo"))
    podInformer := factory.Core().V1().Pods().Informer()

    defer runtime.HandleCrash()

    // start informer ->
    go factory.Start(stopper)

    // start to sync and call list
    if !cache.WaitForCacheSync(stopper, podInformer.HasSynced) {
        runtime.HandleError(fmt.Errorf("Timed out waiting for caches to sync"))
        return
    }

    podInformer.AddEventHandler(cache.ResourceEventHandlerFuncs{
        AddFunc:    onAdd, // register add eventhandler
        UpdateFunc: onUpdate,
        DeleteFunc: onDelete,
    })

    // block the main go routine from exiting
    <-stopper
}

func onAdd(obj interface{}) {
    pod := obj.(*corev1.Pod)
    klog.Infof("POD CREATED: %s/%s", pod.Namespace, pod.Name)
}

func onUpdate(oldObj interface{}, newObj interface{}) {
    oldPod := oldObj.(*corev1.Pod)
    newPod := newObj.(*corev1.Pod)
    klog.Infof(
        "POD UPDATED. %s/%s %s",
        oldPod.Namespace, oldPod.Name, newPod.Status.Phase,
    )
}

func onDelete(obj interface{}) {
    pod := obj.(*corev1.Pod)
    klog.Infof("POD DELETED: %s/%s", pod.Namespace, pod.Name)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, one question after running this application is, I get the log output for the `Update` event as `POD UPDATED. ng/redis-86d74d5b99-z7pxw Running` recursively (continuously). Any idea how can I only trigger this update during only an actual Update?

Comment: could you please provide an example on `checking for container updates between oldPod and newPod in the OnUpdate function` ?

Comment: I think you can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74543618/7360615) example.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like [kubernetes-event-exporter](https://github.com/resmoio/kubernetes-event-exporter) or [kube-eventer](https://github.com/AliyunContainerService/kube-eventer) and send messages with different sinks.

Comment: Thank you, but isn't there a native way of doing this with `client-go` ?

Comment: You could check the code and see how are they procesing the events and so something similar ?