# GoLang - How to get the Kubernetes modifications

Tags: go, kubernetes

I am new to `golang` and I have the following requirement:

1. I have a deployment running with the image `nginx:latest`
2. Then manually someone update this image to something else (eg: `nginx:1.22`)
3. I need to get the old image version and the new image version

So, I researched on the "Shared Informers" in Go Lang. And I wrote this:

```
func main() {

. . . 

    // create shared informers for resources in all known API group versions with a reSync period and namespace
    factory := informers.NewSharedInformerFactoryWithOptions(clientSet, 1*time.Hour, informers.WithNamespace(namespace_to_watch))
    podInformer := factory.Core().V1().Pods().Informer()

    defer runtime.HandleCrash()

    // start informer ->
    go factory.Start(stopper)

    // start to sync and call list
    if !cache.WaitForCacheSync(stopper, podInformer.HasSynced) {
        runtime.HandleError(fmt.Errorf("Timed out waiting for caches to sync"))
        return
    }

    podInformer.AddEventHandler(cache.ResourceEventHandlerFuncs{
        AddFunc:    onAdd, // register add eventhandler
        UpdateFunc: onUpdate,
        DeleteFunc: onDelete,
    })
}

func onUpdate(oldObj interface{}, newObj interface{}) {
    oldPod := oldObj.(*corev1.Pod)
    newPod := newObj.(*corev1.Pod)

    for container_old := range oldPod.Spec.Containers {
       fmt.Printf("Container Old :%s", container_old.Image )
    }

    for container_new := range newPod.Spec.Containers {
       fmt.Printf("Container New :%s", container_new.Image )
    }
  
}
```

As above, according to the `onUpdate` function, I should be getting the two values, instead, I am getting the same value on each update as below:

> Container Old : nginx:latest

> Container New : nginx:latest

> Container Old : nginx:1.22

> Container New : nginx:1.22

> Container Old : nginx:1.22

> Container New : nginx:1.22

Above output is because somehow, the `onUpdate` function is triggered thrice, but as you can see in all the times, the values are the same (for each output).
But I was expecting something like below:

> Container Old : nginx:latest

> Container New : nginx:1.22

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: If the pods are managed by a Deployment, and the Deployment is where the update is happening, then you should try using an informer for Deployments as opposed to Pods.

The reason is that when a new revision of a deployment is rolled out (eg. with new image version), the old pods are _killed_ and _new_ pods are created. You will never get the output you're expecting in your scenario.

Comment: @GeorgeAristy exactly what I thought. Therefore, instead of using an informer for the pods, I should be using it on the `Deployment` right? In that case, am I getting the expected output (eg: old image and the new image) ?

Comment: I haven't used this part of `client-go`, but I would expect it to output the results you expect since it makes more sense from a conceptual basis.

Comment: Hi @GeorgeAristy, it worked :) Thank you so much for your input on this. Been scratching my head since couple of days. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 1):

When an image is updated in the deployments, the pods restart with new image containers and there's no trace of the old pod spec remains. You should watch the deployments instead of the pods and check the image between old deployment and new deployment object. Here's a sample of how you can modify your `onUpdate` method.

```golang
func onUpdate(oldObj interface{}, newObj interface{}) {
    oldDepl := oldObj.(*v1.Deployment)
    newDepl := newObj.(*v1.Deployment)

    for oldContainerID := range oldDepl.Spec.Template.Spec.Containers {
        for newContainerID := range newDepl.Spec.Template.Spec.Containers {
            if oldDepl.Spec.Template.Spec.Containers[oldContainerID].Name == newDepl.Spec.Template.Spec.Containers[newContainerID].Name {
                if oldDepl.Spec.Template.Spec.Containers[oldContainerID].Image != newDepl.Spec.Template.Spec.Containers[newContainerID].Image {
                    fmt.Printf("CONTAINER IMAGE UPDATED FROM %s to %s",
                        oldDepl.Spec.Template.Spec.Containers[oldContainerID].Image, newDepl.Spec.Template.Spec.Containers[newContainerID].Image)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```